# Header Block and Widget area content

Tags: css, wordpress

I am a newbie and designing a Wordpress website (www.dimjaa.org). I am sticking to a minor css problem for last two days but failed to find out the solution. I want to take help from you to solve it and also eager to know root of the cause.
I am using evolve themme. I added header widgets.
Content of the header widget area are Login and Logout links. I want to display these at the top-right of the widget area.[Image of the header-block showing unnecessary padding on both sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FOKh.png)
Two problems that I am facing now are : 1. Background-color of the header-block which holds the widget area can not be changed. Or the header-block can not be covered by the widget area completely (it takes margin in left and right). The header-block can not be targeted properly. Any one of the above may be considered as solution of the issue.
2. Moreover the Login and Logout links can not be placed on the top-right of the area. Even can not be vertically centered. Interestingly when I remove the float: right; then it can be vertically centered. My html and css as below:

```css
   .header-block{
 background-color: red;
    }
    .header-widgets{
 background-color: #CDAE02;
    }
    .user-log a{
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#581845;
 color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 15px;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-right: 1em;
    }
    .user-log a:first-child{
   padding: 4px 13px;
    }
    .user-log a:last-child{
 padding: 4px 8px;
    }
    .user-log a:hover {
 background-color:#B12307;
 font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="user-log">
 <a href="#">Login</a>
 <a href="#">Logout</a>
    </ul>
```

I expect a solution from the experts and also hope to gather knowledge for understanding the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

**container** is a class used by Bootstrap, so you can force that class to have width 100% by using !important in your rule, or you can define a new class called **container-full** and replace it with the container class:

```
.container-full{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, changing the color of header-block won't affect, since it has other children that have other colors and has no space to show the color in the background. You may change the **header-widgets**' color. And it seems like you have padding and margin rules already defined in .widget-content & .header-widgets classes. You either have to change these rules in style.css, or write new rules that contain **!important** command in the end of the rules, so you can force them to affect the rules.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried as you said. But nothing changed. I tried assigning both container: 100% !important; and the 'container-full' option.

Comment: One thing I do not understand. When I inspect the elements it shows the black colored element as '.header-block'. But I can't assign rule to this element. That is, if I assign .header-block {background-color: #fff;} it reflects nothing.

Comment: Now I see you have a rule width:100% for header-widgets, you may remove container class, it should work. And also looks like there is a rule for header-block (background: radial-gradient(circle, #273039, #18212a)) in style.css that blocks the background-color rule, because in css, if you have background rule that is working well with assignments (which is gradient here), the background-color command will not be triggered.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for your continuous response. At last I have managed to do something by trial and error method. I assign this-- header-block {background: none; background-color: #CDAE02; And this removes the black color of the header block and give identical color to the widget area. But still struggling to make the widget area 100% width. And also for placing the Login and Logout to top-right.

Comment: the "container" class forces the div to fix on 1200px width, if you remove that class, you'll see that your div now will have a full width because you have already assigned 100% in other class that shares the same div, header-widgets. and also we aware that the buttons are already on the right hand-side, the reason why they are on bottom is, there is probably a rule such as margin, padding to push them away from top. try these: .header-widgets{ padding-top: 0px !important;}

Comment: Hi I remove the container class and its rules. But still there are the margins. Anyway the good thing is that header-widgets{ padding-top: 0px !important;} works fine. Many thanks.